# When speaking about oneself, should Konjunktiv I or Indikativ be used?

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

I was reading about the use of Konjunktiv I, and read that it is really only used by reporters.

However, this got me thinking, if I were a reporter, and I were talking about something I said, would I still use Konjunktiv I?

For example, if I were to say the following, I know it's true:

> Ich sagte, ich sei müde.

Would I say that, or should I have said:

> Ich sagte, ich bin müde.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first variant given by you,

> Ich sagte, ich sei müde.

sounds a bit stilted but is technically correct.

In spoken language, more typically you would say

> Ich sagte: "Ich bin müde".

or some other variant such as

> Ich war müde und sagte das auch.

By the way, back when IBM sold personal computers, can you guess how Germans would resolve the acronym IBM?

Comment: Thank you! :) And no I don't. How did they?

Comment: 'I'ch 'B'in 'M'ude???

Comment: @detraveller Got it on the first try ;)

Comment: Personally, I'd rather say something like "Ich sagte [doch], dass ich müde bin"

Comment: @TobiasKienzler "Ich sagte doch, dass ich müde bin" drückt Gereiztheit aus darüber, dass einem die Wiederholung abverlangt wird. Ohne "doch" ist es die Erzählung eines bereits vergangenen Zustands. Nun würden einige eine unzulässige Vermischung von Imperfekt und Präsens monieren, andere wiederum den Satz als umgangssprachlich akzeptieren.

Comment: Das stimmt, daher das "doch" in Klammern - andererseits würde ich dazu neigen ein "Ich sagte, ich sei müde" aufgrund der explizit grammatikalischen Aussprache trotz der allgemein gebräuchlicheren Umgangsform ebenfalls als gereizt interpretieren... Ich stelle mir dabei aber auch die Betonung "Ich _sagte_, ich sei müde" VS "Ich sagte: 'Ich bin _müde_'" vor. **edit** Was Imperfekt/Präsens betrifft, kann der Zustand der Müdigkeit ja immer noch vorliegen