# Indirect speech in this context

Tags: grammar, subjunctive, indirect-speech

If I want to say, *I told you I was proud of you*, what do I say?

> Ich sagte dir, dass ich auf dich stolz sei.
>
> Ich sagte dir, dass ich auf dich stolz wäre.

Comment: Indirect speech -> Konjunktiv 1 -> "ich sei". What is your question about, do you know about Konjunktiv? Do you know what to do in indirect speech? Are you unsure if you have to take present tense or preterit?

Comment: @Em1 What is my question about? I don't know if I can get any more concise than that. I just want to know which of the versions in my question is correct. Is that so hard to give an answer to? And yes, theoretically I know everything about grammar. That's why I almost always ask this way: If I want to say... Because I'm trying to check if theory does indeed follow in the steps of practice. So what is so hard about that? This is my own method of really mastering grammatical theory.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. Both sentences are fine (but _stolz auf dich_ would be more common), but they mean slightly different things.

Comment: Use "..., dass ich stolz auf dich bin."! everything else is wrong or means something different

Comment: @Emanuel: Aber im Original ist es doch "I was", wieso übersetzt man es nicht "dass ich stolz auf Dich war"? Der Stolz könnte bereits Geschichte sein. Und wie würde der Brite sagen, dass er stolz war, aber nicht mehr ist?

Comment: @user unknown: Das erklärt tatsächlich der Link von falkb. Vergangenheit wäre _had been proud_.

Comment: Indirekte Rede in Deutsch, soweit sie nicht im Konjunktiv steht ist wie eine direkte Rede mit anderer Satzstellung. Das gilt auch für Sachen wie "Ich dachte, ..." oder "Ich wusste nicht,..." Der erste Teil des Satzes transportiert uns sozusagen in die Vergangenheit, der zweite Teil ist dann "live". Wenn man zum Beispiel sagt... "Ich wusste, wo du bist." dann meint man, dass man im Moment des Denkens weiß wo jemand ist. Sagt man "Ich wusste, wo du warst" dann wusste man im Moment des Denkens wo jemand VORHER gewesen ist... bevor man das denkt. Deutsch ist ein bisschen eigen was das angeht

Answer (score 4):

The German appropriation is neither `wäre` nor `sei` as you suggested, but simply

> Ich hab dir gesagt, dass ich stolz auf dich bin.

Indirect speech works with a different mechanism in English (Please, read about [backshift of tenses](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/reported.htm) to understand how it works in English). `Ich bin`, which is "I am" (Simple Present) in English, turns to "I was" (Simple Past) in indirect speech, because of that mentioned English grammar rule. That is why you get `I was proud of you` but it's originated from `... dass ich stolz auf dich bin`. German has no backshift of tenses here, so it remains `bin` in this language, and it does not turn to `sei`, `wäre`, `war` or similar words.

We also use German Indikativ `ich bin` here since be are sure it is as it is, we know we were proud since we have lived it. Konjunktiv is used if the fact is not sure or true, which may be the case if we speak about another person and we were not there when it happened; then we would rather use `er sagte, er sei`. More details about Indikativ and Konjunktiv can be found [here](http://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/indirekte-rede). `Sei` puts uncertainty in the sentence and indicates it may be not true, but it's actually only used in written German, and you must not use it. For example `I told you I was proud of you, but that was a lie` can be expressed in German either a bit stilted/antiquated `Ich habe dir gesagt, ich sei stolz auf dich, aber das war gelogen` or also (preferred) `Ich habe dir gesagt, ich bin stolz auf dich, aber das war gelogen`.

`Ich sagte, ... ich ... wäre` would need an additional condition with `wenn`, for instance `Ich sagte, dass ich stolz auf dich wäre, wenn du dich mehr anstrengen würdest.`. In this case you tell a conditional in indirect speech.

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html

Comment: @falkb I don't need to read about "backshift of tenses" In English. That was not what I asked. That's not even what this site is for. We're not on this site dedicated to the German language to ask questions about English.

Comment: @falkb: in German it doesn't turn to anything in fact... the second part stays in present. You really should remove the link since it has nothing to do with the question

Comment: I think your basic idea for including it was fine but maybe you should elaborate a bit and point out the different mechanics between English and German in that regard... or at least say that the links tells us how it DOESN'T work in German ;)

Comment: Now I've edited again. Sorry for not understanding the question background at first sight. Yes, one needs a while to get it what the underlying logic of using `bin`, `sei` and `wäre` actually is.

Comment: _Sei_ and _wäre_ are possible as well, with _sei_ bring more formal and _wäre_ more colloquial. However, they suggest that the statement wasn't actually true: _Ich habe gesagt, daß ich stolz auf dich sei, aber das war gelogen._ It's a bit different again if I'm citing someone else's statement, where _sei_ may just indicate that I don't want to judge the truthfulness: _Er hat gesagt, daß er stolz auf dich sei._

Comment: Much better, but there're still some issues. "Konjunktiv is used if the fact is not sure or true [...] 'Ich sagte, ... ich ... wäre' would need an additional condition with wenn". In oral conversation, K1 is indeed used to express uncertainty and K2 (wäre-Form) is used to express that you're quite sure, that it's not true. (Ex. in next comment). There are, however, more reasons to use K2. E.g. Indikativ == K1 (DR:"Ich habe"-IR:Er habe) or if K1 uncommon ("hättest" instead of "habest"). - In your last ex. the direct speech was already Konjunktiv. "Kind, ich wäre ja so stolz auf dich, wenn ..."

Comment: And now the examples for difference in conotation when using Indikativ, K1 and K2.: "Was hat er gesagt?" - "Dass er zu Hause ist" -> Er ist jetzt wohl wirklich zu Hause // "Dass er zu Hause sei" -> Ich bin mir nicht sicher, im Hintergrund hörte ich Geräusche, die anderes vermuten lassen. // "Dass er zu Hause wäre" -> Ich konnte aber eindeutig HIntergrundgeräusche indentifizieren und weiß, dass er lügt.

Comment: For **non-colloquial** German, *bin* is always wrong here, since indirect speech (or similar) is always in one of the subjunctive (Konjunktiv) moods. The default case is subjunctive I (here: *sei).* The subjunctive II (here: *wäre)* is used to indicate that the statement is not true (or if the subjunctive I is identical to the indicative, which is however not the case here).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for what a native speaker would say in an everyday conversation, use:

> Ich habe dir gesagt, dass ich stolz auf dich bin.

It may not be absolutely correct, gramatically, but everything else would sound too formal, use it only in written language!

Comment: I merely wanted to know which of those two sentences is correct in German. If none is, you should have said so. If only one is, you should have told me which one is. But I don't need to hear that "It may not be absolutely correct"; this is an amateur way of dealing with grammar. Any grammar. And I certainly didn't want to hear that "everything else would sound too formal, use it only in written language!". I may know nothing about German, which is almost entirely true, but your way of answering questions about it is completely unsatisfactory.

Comment: marsze, your sentence is grammatically fine but not more or less formal than "Ich sagte, ich sei stolz auf dich" and "Ich sagte, dass ich auf dich stolz sei". - The second sentence of OP (@indoxica), however, is wrong.

Comment: @indoxica If you "merely wanted to know" *which* was correct, or which rules apply, you should have said so in your original question, not a vague "what do I say..."

Comment: Questions on *"what do I say"* can not always be answered with a grammatically correct version. In this case the answer above is correct, as it is probably the most common variant in **spoken** German. This is not so in a written text, where grammar rules for indirect speech are different but this was not asked here. We should treat people who contribute here with respect. In case we feel our question is not answered - use your votes, but please don't accuse people of not having understood the question properly. It may then also be that the question needs an edit.

Answer (score 2):

In **non-colloquial** speech the variant with *sei* is almost certainly what you want to use. The default mood for reported speech is the subjunctive I (here: *sei)* and using it does not indicate any uncertainty about the correctness of the reported information – and thus it does not make any difference that you are reporting your own speech (see also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6888)).

Using the subjunctive II (here: *wäre)* would state that you do not consider true whatever is reported. So, in your example you would only use this, if you lied about being proud.

Note that the subjunctive II can be also used instead of the subjunctive I, if the latter is identical to an indicative form (which is not the case here). The subjunctive II in turn can also be replaced by a *würde* construct, if it is identical to a past indicative form.

In **colloquial** speech it is most common that no subjunctive at all is used (i.e., *bin* instead of *sei* or *wäre).*

Answer (score -1):

> Ich sagte dir, dass ich auf dich stolz sei.

no, you don't speak about yourself in the disjunctive

> Ich sagte dir, dass ich auf dich stolz wäre.

no, same, --> In the past you said: ich bin auf dich stolz. So in order to reflect that the correct expression is:

Ich sagte dir (doch), das ich auf dich stolz bin. (Warum hörst du mir denn nicht zu?) Warum hast du mir denn nicht zugehört?